# using dashes between string literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, xss

I just noticed that you can make an XSS attack by using dashes between string literals in javascript:

ie:

```js
var foo = 'bar'-alert(1)-'baz'; 
//this will display the alert
```

my question is, what's doing the js interpreter there? **what does it mean** using dashes like that?
I tought it was just an aritmetic operator.

----- UPDATE -----

Sorry, I didn't explained the real context for the xss attack:

I agree, the alert(1) doesn't look very harmful. But is a real example actually, that I got from a security scan made with [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp)
. The hoster is bugging me with it, but I would suggest to take it as a **false positive** vulnerability.

Anyway, I'm using a **querystring** parameter for **redirección**:

```
http://mysite.com/foo.php?returnto=bar.php
```

it is also made with javascript:

```php
echo '<script>alert("bye!");window.location="'.escapeXSS($_REQUEST['returnto']).'";</script>';
```

the attacker may insert an anonymous function there, to by excecuted before redirecting:

```
http://mysite.com/foo.php?returnto=bar.php'-function(){/* do something */}()-'
```

the result would be:

```js
<script>alert("bye!");windows.location='bar.php'-function(){/* do something */}()-'';</script>
```

that indeed, gets the function excecuted (depending on the quality of the php escaping function).

Comment: Can you demonstrate how this may result in an XSS attack? I'm not convinced yet.

Comment: It's literally the same problem had you used `+` instead of `-`: the code `'bar'+alert(1)+'baz'` still executes the function call. In general, I don't see how `escapeXSS($_REQUEST['returnto'])` can do anything useful if it leaves function calls intact. It must not be very good at its job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interpreter is simply casting each sub-expression to try to form a mathematical expression.

Instead of:

`var foo = 1 - 2 - 1;`

you have an expression that ends up being:

`var foo = NaN - NaN - NaN;`

which is why `foo` is `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` is executed not because it has dashes in the string, but because you closed the string after `bar`, "subtracted" from it the return of the `alert()` and subtracted from it the string `baz`. So the function `alert()` will always be called. If you do not want it to occur, just do not close and reopen the string:

```
var foo = 'bar-alert(1)-baz';
```

Actually, I do not see how it could result in an XSS attack. Any string passed to your code would actually be a string like the one above.